# How to remove modules via ftp?

Tags: 7

I need to know how to remove modules via ftp, i activated some modules, and now im getting constantly errors like

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function views_include() in /home/a7898297/public_html/sites/all/modules/eva/eva.module on line 113

so how can i remove custom modules?

Comment: Get a look on [Disabling or Enabling modules manually in the database](https://drupal.org/node/157632) docs, and on [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush).

Comment: Hi, I've rolled back the edit you just made as that would render existing answers invalid. If you have a different question to ask, please ask a new question, or edit this one in such a way as to not change the original question. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable the module on http://example.com/admin/modules first. That should take care of your error messages.

If your administration interface is not accessible - caused by the error message - you could access the database directly and disable the module in the system table - as suggested by Mołot and outlined in https://drupal.org/node/157632.

Additionally to disabling the module, you should also uninstall it - which will remove any configuration and data associated with this module from the database: http://example.com/admin/modules/uninstall (at least it should, if it is properly written).

Now, you can safely remove the module from the modules directory, if you want to. Since the module is disabled and uninstalled, it will not interfere with your Drupal installation, however, it is advisable to clean up the modules directory, and move the module to a location outside the webroot - to avoid issues if the module has security holes and the web-server is (mis)configured to allow direct execution of modules.

Before you do all this, I would save a backup of the database and the custom module, in case the functionality and data might be needed after all.

You can of course do all of this also on the command line using drush - since you asked about ftp, I assume you do not have ssh access.

Comment: "there is no harm in leaving it there." - only if module does not provide security holes and webserver is configured in a way that prevents direct execution of module's files. *Usually* both conditions are met as inc and module are never executed and even if they are, they would not be able to bootstrap Drupal, but usually is weaker than always. I would suggest removing what is not used anymore.

Comment: @Mołot: of course you are correct, thanks. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer (disabling the plugin manually via database), you can also do it via FTP if you worry about damaging the database.

Find the module's *.module* file and plainly delete its contents (but leave the empty file there). This will usually make any fatal errors disappear since the module now does almost nothing. Now you can access your admin interface again and uninstall the offending plugin.

For me this is the most straightforward way.

Answer (score -4):

You must install the FireFtp addon in Mozilla Firefox, connect the host, and delete the modules. That is not working for you. You must disable modules from admin/modules and uninstall them from admin/modules/uninstall; that would delete any database table that the modules created.

I would recommended to edit modules/eva/eva.module on line 113, and delete the `views_include()` function; after that, disable and uninstall the modules.

Comment: Hello. If you are trying to add anything to what Ursula already wrote, it got lost. Please use sentences, paragraphs etc. Try to write professional.

Comment: i think you Don't know and Don't understand what the problem is. this user after install this modules get fatal error in all of pages because of this he can't disable any modules .

Comment: @masoudsoroush I've removed the childish, patronising part of your comment. We expect and require professional behaviour at all times here; please bear that in mind when posting comments in the future.